# Control edit permission via google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I control my own edit permission (via google apps script) to a certain range in google sheet?

The code below isn't working.

```
function protect_sheet() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getRange('A1:D10');
  var protection = range.protect();
  
  };

function unprotect_sheet() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
      protection.remove();
    }
  }
  
}

protect_sheet();
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Calling `range.protect` doesn't really do anything until you follow that up with `addEditor` and/or `removeEditor` per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect). Although in general I don't think  you can remove edit access from yourself in this way if that's your intention. When I've wanted to do something like this, I've used a deployed web app as a middle man.

Comment: @MiguelRiveraRios

Comment: @MiguelRiveraRios Context: I have a handcrafted CRM in google sheets which I share with my employees, but I don't want them to insert data manually, they have to click a button to open a form where they insert the data, then  the form feeds the table in the CRM. Therefore I want to block edit permission to all of them, except during the use of the form, which should be the only way to insert the data.

So that's why I want to control edit permission via script. The script should read the opening/loading of the form and allow edit, and remove edit permission when closing the form.

Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha, TBH I still think fiddling with permissions in this way is overly complicated. I think it would be easier to just manually protect the data sheet you don't want employees editing, and then have the form submit to a deployed web app that runs under your authorization which then appends the new data to the spreadsheet. Now that I think about it, you'd most likely need to use a web app anyways, since I don't think people can add themselves as editors to protected ranges that they don't already have access to.

Comment: @MiguelRiveraRios exactly. Sorry for the bad code up there, I adjusted for the addEditor and removeEditor, but it didn't work anyway. My investigation points to your explanation, that I can't control the permission for a protected range.

Comment: Well, gotta work with the webapp. Thanks for the help! Cheers!